# WCF Service Error 400 Bad Request In VS2017

Tags: wcf

I have a very simple WCF Service Project in VS2017. But I keep getting error 400 when I try to visit the endpoints. I have read the other questions posted here about the same issue and I have tried them with no luck so far.

My Service Contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "GET",
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
            UriTemplate = "/GetData/{value}")]
    string GetData(string value);
}
```

My Service:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    public string GetData(string value)
    {
        return string.Format("You entered: {0}", value);
    }
}
```

My Web.Config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" name="WCGFService1.Service">
        <endpoint address="" contract="WCGFService1.IService" binding="webHttpBinding">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>
```

When I visit `http://localhost:61648/Service.svc/GetData/12`, I get HTTP 400 Bad Request. I've tried with browser and POSTman. What am I doing wrong?

I am using VS2017. My IService.cs and Service.cs are inside the App_Code folder whereas the 
Service.svc is in the root folder. Also, when I try to add the `name` & `contract` in web.config, VS2013 suggests me the namespace and the interface/class name, whereas, VS2017 is not suggesting me anything so I have to manually type it.

Also, in VS2013, the Interface and Class were located in the root folder instead of the App_Code folder. The project is a WCF Application in VS2017. My .NET Version is 4.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, had a few problems in the web.config file:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <!-- Fix 1: Added a endpointBehavoir with webHttp -->
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>

    </behaviors>

    <services>
      <!-- Fix 2: Instead of using the full name (WCGFService1.Service), used just the class name (Service) -->
      <service behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" name="Service">
      <!-- Fix 3: Same thing here, used just the IService instead of full name, also, used the aforementioned endpointBehavoir -->
        <endpoint address="" contract="IService" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="web">
        </endpoint>
      </service>
    </services>

    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

That did it for me, for whatever reason, in VS2013, it would not work if you don't provide the full name (namespace and class/interface name) but in VS2017, it works only if you provide just the class/interface name.